# How to get an exact match with multiple where clauses in relation from other table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, `items` and `item_values`.

```
items    item_values
-----    -----------
id       item_id
name     value_id
```

I've set up a relationship between these two tables in my `Item` model.

```
function values() {
    return $this->hasMany(ItemValues::class, "item_id", "id");
}
```

I have an array containing `value_id` for example like `[1, 2, 3, ...]` and I want to get all items from `items` table if they exist in `item_values` and if the `value_id` is in the array above. I want it to be an exact match, so I don't want it to display all items with either one of the values, but I want them to display all items that have all of the values.

```
$item = Items::orderBy("created_at", "desc");
if($request->has("values")) {
    $appends["values"] = $request->input("values");
    $values = $request->input("values");

    $findValues = $item->whereHas("values", function($query) use($values) {
        foreach($values as $value) {
            $query->where("value_id", $value);
        }
    });
}

$items = $item->paginate(10);
```

This works for a single value, however, if I attempt to search for multiple values it will return 0 results.

When I print out the query it returns:

```
select * from `items` where exists (select * from `item_values` where `items`.`id` = `item_values`.`item_id` and `value_id` = ? and `value_id` = ?) order by `created_at` desc
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: What ORM or framework is that?

Comment: Is there a `values` table as well?

Answer (score 2):

> using `INNER JOIN` will only return those rows from `item` table which match exactly with
>   `item_values` table

suppose `value_id array` contains [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] then raw SQL query would be like this.

```
SELECT items.* 
FROM items
INNER JOIN item_values on items.id = item_values.item_id
WHERE item_values.value_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

> WHERE clause returns those item rows having value_id in values array

lets convert it into the Query Builder syntax now

```
if($request->has("values")) {
    $values = $request->input("values");

    $items = Items::join('item_values', 'item_values.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
             ->whereIn('item_values.value_id', $values)->get();
}
```

Comment: FYI, this isn't Eloquent, it's query builder. Setting up proper relationships on the models means you don't have to deal with SQL syntax like joins.

Comment: And now you've just repeated my answer LOL

Comment: I'm not looking for a `whereIn`, I believe, because it will return rows where it has either of the values. I need it to contain every single value in `value_id` array, not just one or two.

Comment: @P.Nick can you please share data of `value_id` column from `item_values` db table?